# Is there any eclipse plugin for Cherrypy?

Tags: cherrypy

Can anybody suggest me IDE for CherryPy ? Is there plugin for Eclipse ? I have installed PyDev and I have option Django but not CherryPy.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've have PyDev configured your almost there.  So far there is not a cherrypy plugin for eclipse.

Download the version of cherrypy you would like to use.  Using the command line navigate to the directory cherrypy downloaded to and execute the following command:

```
python setup.py install
```

http://www.cherrypy.org/wiki/CherryPyInstall

Andrew